# Restricting a covering map to a homeomorphism on a neighbourhood of a subspace

Tags: general-topology, smooth-manifolds

Let $\pi : X \to Y$ be a covering map between smooth manifolds and $Z \subset Y$ an embedded submanifold. Suppose that there is a smooth map $\varphi : Z \to X$ such that $\pi \circ \varphi = i$, where $i : Z \hookrightarrow Y$ is the inclusion. Is there a neighbourhood $U$ of $i(Z)$ in $X$ and a neighbourhood $V$ of $Z$ in $Y$ such that the restriction $\pi : U \to V$ is a homeomorphism?

Comment: Neighborhood $V$ of $X$ in $Z$?

Comment: @PaulFrost Yes.

Comment: I didn't mean the word "neigborhood", but the fact that $X$ is not contained in $Z$. I guess you want to have a neighborhood $V$ of $Z$ in $Y$.

Comment: @PaulFrost Yes, that was a typo. Thanks for pointing it out.